# How to integrate a Streamlit webapp with Active Directory (AD) Single Sign On (SSO)

Tags: active-directory

We are building a [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) webapp and currently using the [Streamlit Authenticator](https://github.com/mkhorasani/Streamlit-Authenticator) package to log in with a locally managed username/password.

Assuming our organization has a full suite of Microsoft and AWS tools at hand. What way forward would you recommend to integrate with Active Directory (AD) for a Single Sign On (SSO)?